# Does this sentence make sense? ( In the room is so hot.)

Tags: grammar

I saw the sentence 'In the room is so hot.' on the internet.
Can a prepositional phrase be the subject?
Is this sentence acceptable to you?
Please, give me the answer.

Comment: It is not idiomatic. It should be written "It is so hot in the room", or *The room is so hot inside".

Comment: PPs denoting a location can function as subject ("_Behind the sofa_ is a good place to hide it"). But your example is not natural, and the PP is best seen as a preposed locative complement. The basic order would be _It is so hot in the room_.

Answer (score 1):

Prepositional phrases are arguably on occasion used as subjects or objects.

CalifJim has addressed this issue at [EnglishForums](https://www.englishforums.com/English/CanPrepositionalPhraseServeSubject/vxjgd/post.htm):

> [Y]ou can make a prepositional phrase a 'sort of' subject by pulling
>   it to the beginning. The resulting sentences are 'pretty lame',
>   however, and not all grammarians will likely agree that these phrases
>   are true subjects, since the sentences can be analyzed as something
>   like cleft transformations of an underlying sentence with a different
>   'true' subject.
>
> *In the office is where you'll find him.* [You'll find him in the
>   office.]
>
> *Before the war was when they met.* [They met before the war.]
>
> *With great care was how they proceeded.* [They proceeded with great
>   care.]

There is a further complication here in that the 'underlying sentence' uses *weather it* (It is so hot in/side the room), deleted in the given transformation, which probably further undermines idiomaticity.

..............

The conversational substitution of 'in' for 'inside' here will also worry some people (like Nur).